# unexpected closure result in javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

```
exports.list = function(callback){

  var result = model.find({}, function(err, objects){
    callback(null, objects)
  });
  return result;
}
```

**Q**: Why is the above code a closure? Is it because the function parameter calls the function `callback` which is nested in it?

**Q**: does this cause an infinite loop, since the function is calling itself through its parameter?

**Q**: will the above function work if `callback` wasn't defined anywhere?

Comment: One could argue that all JS functions are closures, as the parent scope is there automatically (with no extra work on your part) if you want variables from it.  Some just don't use those variables (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q:** Why is the above code a closure? Is it because the function parameter calls the function callback which is nested in it?

**A:** As Mike explained, once an outside var is used inside a function, you create a closure.

**Q:** does this cause an infinite loop

**A:** I assume `function(err, objects)` will fire only once for the model, so no it won't. You would create an infinite loop if you call `callee` (or self)

**Q:** will the above function work if callback wasn't defined anywhere?

**A:** you will get an error `ReferenceError: callback is not defined`

Comment: referring to @slebetman's answer, will i still get a `ReferenceError: callback is not defined` if i call `exports.list()`, where `callback` is not defined elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

The others have already answered most of your questions. However, from your comments I see that you may still be confused about the last question:

- **Q:** will the above function work if callback wasn't defined anywhere?

Answer: `callback` is already defined in the above code. And here's where `callback` is defined:

```
exports.list = function(callback){ // <---- the callback variable defined here

  var result = model.find({}, function(err, objects){
    callback(null, objects) // <-- callback is used here
  });
  return result;
}
```

Now, by the strict meaning of the word "defined", callback is defined as the parameter of `eports.list()`. If you pass anything other than a function (or nothing) the `exports.list()` callback would still technically be "defined" but its value would not be a function.

Comment: thanks a lot, that REALLY cleared up my confusion because i come from a Java background where a function with a parameter must be defined. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

it is a closure because `callback` is captured inside the model.find() code from enclosing function scope assigned to `exports.list`.

Comment: yup i got the captured bit. but its now a parameter of the function, instead of examples of `callback` being called by other functions outside the scope of `list`

Comment: this example just expects you to call the list function bound to exports and pass it the callback. something like `exports.list(function(arg1, objList) { console.log("stuff"); })`

Comment: i see. in other words, i have to define `callback` right? As i dont see it being defined as a function elsewhere..

Comment: yes, you need to provide the callback. the exports.list function would just use whatever callback you pass it to do some setting up or whatever first before calling the custom code you give it.

Comment: @bouncingHippo: `callback` is already defined in your code. Here: `exports.list = function(callback){ // <-- callback defined here`